# ASP.NET ImageResizer not resizing GIFs and PNGs

Tags: imageresizer

I had ImageResizer set up for years in my app and it is serving/resizing JPGs fine (I use presets) but today I wanted to resize a spacer.gif and it did not do anything. I then tried with spacer.png and it also doesn't touch it (no resize, image rendered at 1x1 pixels).

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [covered in Basic Usage](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/docs/basics), ImageResizer does not upscale by default. You will need to specify `?scale=both&width=200` to upscale tiny images.

This is unlikely to have anything to do with the image format (namely gif/png).

Comment: totally missed that;)